# Python unresolved import VisualStudio

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, import

I want to start learning some basics in python. My IDE is Visual Studio Code. Every time I try to do an import, I got the error `unresolved import 'someInput'Python(unresolved-import)`, no matter which module I am trying to import. I already searched in the internet, but didn't find a solution that works for me. (e.g. https://roundthenet.com/how-to-solve-the-unresolved-import-warning-when-using-visual-studio-code-for-python/).

My vscode settings.json:

```
{
    "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
    "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
    "java.semanticHighlighting.enabled": true,
    "files.exclude": {
        "**/.classpath": true,
        "**/.project": true,
        "**/.settings": true,
        "**/.factorypath": true
    },
    "python.languageServer": "Microsoft",
    "git.ignoreWindowsGit27Warning": true,
    "workbench.editorAssociations": [
        {
            "viewType": "jupyter.notebook.ipynb",
            "filenamePattern": "*.ipynb"
        }
    ]
}
```

Python version is 3.9.0 (64 Bit). In my terminal (windows) I can use the `pip install ...` command without any errors. Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you run pip-V in the terminal to show the corresponding path to pip? I image that pip is installing to a different Python than what VS Code is using.

Comment: `pip 20.3 from c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.6)`
@JasonCook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment on pip -V, running "pip install.." in the VS Code terminal will install to Python 3.6. You original posts states you are using Python 3.9.0 and I assume this is displayed in the very bottom left of the VS Code window.

Try to install in the VS Code terminal using the correct version of pip like:
pip3.9 install....

You can also switch to the 3.6 Python interpreter in VS Code

1. Click the version 3.9.0 in the bottom left of VS code.
2. Ctrl+Shift+P > search Python: Select Interpreter

Comment: @CodeIsLaw I would also check into virtual environments. This way you can select the virtual environment Python interpreter for VS Code, and also have that virtual environment activated in the VS Code terminal so using "pip install..." will install to that same version. It's a good way to manage multiple Python installations.

Here's a link to the VS documentation on Python virtual environments
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments